# How to save time info without date in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp

I'm trying to save time information (so hour, minute, seconds) without additional date information in `pyspark`. Is there a way to do this? I could use a timestamp, but this would require filling in the date information to some standard nonsense date. Is there a type just for time information?

Example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('1997-02-28 10:30:00',)], ['t'])
df = (
    df
    .select(F.to_timestamp(df.t).alias('timestamp'))
    .withColumn('time_col', F.some_function_i_dont_know(F.col('timestamp')))
)
```

Please note that I do not want to use the `date_format` function because that just creates a string.

Comment: From you code, you are converting your "string" (date+time) into some timestamp with the time you want. I could think of a few ways, one of which would be to just select the chars that are related to  time...I.e timestamp[-8:] or if your datetime is some other datatype.....have you looked at the datetime library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in [**spark**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html) there is no type for time but you can use `int` (or) `string`.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("select int(date_format(current_Timestamp(),'HHmmssSSS'))as time").\
printSchema()
#root
# |-- time: integer (nullable = true)



spark.sql("select int(date_format(current_Timestamp(),'HHmmssSSS')) as time").\
show()
#+---------+
#|     time|
#+---------+
#|130250300|
#+---------+

#as string
spark.sql("select (date_format(current_Timestamp(),'HH:mm:ss.SSS')) as time").show()
#+------------+
#|        time|
#+------------+
#|13:04:08.527|
#+------------+
```