# How to convert a str in hh:mm:ss format type to timestamp type without (year month day info) in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert the str type hh:mm:ss to timestamp type without (year month day info), below is my code, however, it still pops out the 1970-01-01 info.

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('10:30:00',)], ['date'])
df2 = (df1
    .withColumn("new_date", to_timestamp("date", 'HH:mm:ss')))
df2.show(2)
```

sample output:  1970-01-01 10:30:00;

How to ignore the year-month-day info in this case? Can someone please help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This would be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69045740/how-to-save-time-info-without-date-in-pyspark

Comment: @Vaebhav thanks for the info. Then I guess there will be no such choice. But, I am wondering, whether I can drop the 1970-01-01 info.

Comment: if you wish to drop the date part , then you will have to keep it as string , which is your input in the first place, you can still keep to convert it to `timestamp` and any operations that you wish to perform on will still be applicable.

Another way would be implicitly add the date part urself , i.e. current date/static etc